# Remove, ignore or prevent null characters in a string in IE

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, date

Encountering null characters in strings from a data file, which cause problems in IE.  A codepen is here;

http://codepen.io/gradualstudent/pen/DBExf

Am able to parse dates in a datafile in Chrome, Firefox, Safari on mac and Chrome and Firefox on Windows, but not in IE (9, 10, 11) .  The data file is a simple CSV read in with `d3.csv(...)`

An example such string is ostensibly `"4/23/2014"`.  But it fails to parse as a Date in IE:

```
JSON.stringify(dt);  //  "4/23/2014"
new Date(dt); // [date] Invalid Date
Date.parse(dt); // NaN
```

This is despite the fact that a string literal parses fine:

```
new Date("4/23/2014") // [date] Wed Apr 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400
```

It turns out that the strings in the datafile have lots of null characters:

```
var dta = [];
for (var i=0; i<dt.length; i++) { dta[i] = dt.charAt(i); }
JSON.stringify(dta);
["‎", "4", "‎", "/", "‎", "2", "3", "‎", "/", "‎", "2", "0", "1", "4", "‎"]
```

How do I either strip such characters or prevent them from being read in?

Comment: try `dt.split("").filter(Boolean).join("")`. You'll need to shim the `.filter()` method in older ID.

Comment: Looks like it's some funky character. Try this `dt.split("").filter(function(c) {
  return c.charCodeAt() !== 8206;
}).join("")`

Comment: The Boolean filter is brilliant.   It works -- but discovered that these are no ordinary null characters, they are truthy.  This solution fails if I simply type .`""` in the split, but works if I copy/paste the `""` from the array.  Revised the codepen to show this.  This must be some weird encoding?

Comment: The right-to-left character? Wild. Rather than do heavy string processing of datafiles in an already data-intensive app to remove nonprintable characters, I'll see if I can find out how these characters got inserted. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you can eliminate them at the source, that would be better. Good luck!

Comment: `JSON.Stringify` puts quotes around the result. So you are actually doing `new Date('"4/23/2014"')`. That may work in some browsers, but not in others, as you have found. Before you call `new Date`, you'll need to re-parse the result, or remove the quotes.

Comment: If you're unable to reliably clean up the source, it may help to run a quick perl, Powershell, or other script to clean things up as an intermediary step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning the input where the issue happens is going to be a much cleaner solution. But if you have to clean the output before parsing this may just work.

If you run a regex against the date-string before parsing it it appears to solve the issue.
Snippet from your Codepen with Regex added.

```js
var dt = "‎4‎/‎23‎/‎2014‎";
$("#dt").html(new Date(dt))

//Clear everything except expected items in a date

// Ordinary null character
var dt1 = dt.replace(/[^0-9/]/ig, "");
$("#dt1").html(new Date(dt1))


//Or to specifically target the character causing the issues

// Ordinary null character
var dt2 = dt.replace(/[\u200E]/ig, "");
$("#dt2").html(new Date(dt2))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
dt: <code id="dt"></code>
<br>dt1: <code id="dt1"></code>
<br>dt2: <code id="dt2"></code>
```